# Solving particular case of Bernoulli Equation

Tags: differential-equations, homework

I have a Bernoulli equation (attached below). It needs to be converted to ODE. I tried to solve it by a separation of variables, but I could not. Can anyone help me with the code for this, please?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it already an ODE? What is $a$?

Comment: a  in this equation equals to 2

Comment: You should read the documentation on ODEs. I am very rusty on differential equations so this is not a full answer, but basically you need to substitute $y$ for $1/u$ which gives you a new differential equation which is linear $A u(x)-B+u'(x) = 0$ . See here where I've given the quick method and the linear method https://pastebin.com/dn7VNvXU

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation for info on how to transform to linear

Comment: What's "the formula of the textbook for linear ODEs"?

Answer (score 1):

```
ode = y'[t] == A y[t] - B y[t]^2;
DSolve[ode, y[t], t]
```

> ```
> {{y[t] -> (A E^(A t + A C[1]))/(1 + B E^(A t + A C[1]))}}
> ```
>
> [image]